# SQL Join - All stores where employee has NOT worked

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Basically what I want to do is get a list of stores the employee has **NOT** worked at. The problem is that the query is returning a list of stores that other employees have worked at. So for example, if employee.ID = 1&2 have both worked at store.ID = 2, then the result set will include store.ID = 2 which I don't want because Employee.ID = 1 has worked there.

```
SELECT
   stores.name
FROM
   stores
LEFT JOIN
   employeeStoreRelationshipTable
ON
   employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeID = employee.id
WHERE
   employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeID IS NULL    
OR
   employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeID <> [actual Employee ID]
```

This is because the join is including it as there's no filter to store.ID = 2 because another employee other than employee.ID = 1 has worked there...

**UPDATE:** Added info as requested:

```
Employee table
id, name
1, Bob
2, John

Store table
ID, name
1, 111 main st.
2, 222 main st.
3, 333 main st.
4, 444 main st.

EmployeeStoreRelationshipTable
employeeID, storeID
1, 1
1, 3
2, 3
3, 4
```

So in this case the results should be:

Employee 1 hasn't worked in stores 2 and 4.

The query results are 2, 3, and 4. Store 3 appears because Employee.ID = 2 has worked in store 3.

Comment: For what database?  [LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is only better on MySQL, when columns are not nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Comment: employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeID = employee.id 
  should be employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeID = employeeId? or is there a table missing in the join

Comment: Give sample data and output required.

Comment: Consider my answer. If you test mine you will find my query performs better that Alex's

Comment: Not sure which answer to go with, they both work. I can't really attest in terms of performance because my dataset isn't large enough to have a significant impact (and it depends on the RDBMS itself).

Comment: I think they both may perform differently under different circumstances. If your tables are small and performance is not an issue - choose the one that is shorter :). Otherwise, spend some time analyzing your case and read the article I linked to.

Comment: I'm going to go with the one that makes more sense to me since it's smaller tables and therefore performance isn't a big issue in this scenario. I upvoted both of you guys. Great answers! Thank you.

Comment: FYI, as the number of stores increases, my query will remain roughly constant, but the time the other one takes wills grow linearly with the number of rows in `stores`. It is fair to say that for a small number of stores, the difference may not be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from stores s
where ID not in (
    select StoreID
    from EmployeeStoreRelationshipTable
    where employeeId=[employeeID])
```

This does only two queries - the inner one generates a list of IDs he's used, the outer one gives you all the *other* stores.

Answer (score 2):

This query is called [anti-join](http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/semijoins.html) and should look something like this (may need to tune it):

```
select name from stores s where 
     not exists (select 1 from employyeRelTable er 
                 where er.employeeId=[employeeID] 
                   and er.storeID=s.storeID)
```

Comment: This will not perform well: You're doing one query for every store row

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
and employeeStoreRelationshipTable.employeeId = [actual Employee ID]
```

to the join condition and remove form the `where` clause